# In Java, how to configure the maximum CPU-cores for a thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, threadpool, executorservice

For example, I have 2 thread pools in the same computer. One for IO-intensive tasks (such as remoteReading and remoteWriting, let's call it `ReadWritePool`), and the other for CPU-intensive tasks (let's call it `ComputationPool`). The maximum pool size for `ReadWritePool` is 20. And the pool size for `ComputationPool` is 5.

Then I have a 4-core CPU. I want to assign 3 cores for `ComputationPool` and 1 core for `ReadWritePool`. I do this because I don't want the threads in `ReadWritePool` to compete with the threads `CompuationalPool`, while competition within the same Pool is allowed.

Is it a good practice to split different kinds of tasks into different pools like this? If so, how to set the maximum CPU core a thread pool can use?

Comment: Most of the time you should let the scheduler of the OS decide how to assign threads to cores and your only worry should be not to run too many CPU intensive threads at the same time (as you'd be putting unnecessary pressure on the scheduler). It's very rare that "pinning" threads (or thread pools) to cores is necessary or useful. And I'm not aware of an easy way to do it in Java. For example, it's very likely that the core doing the I/O work will be idle most of the time and could do some CPU work "on the side".

Comment: As @JoachimSauer said, you should try to use your resources efficiently rather than allocating different cores for different threads. Having said that, there's a thread pinning library in Java - [Java Thread Affinity](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Thread-Affinity)